# Using a Views Output as Options in a Webform in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views, webforms

I have a list of articles on my site and currently I have a View that lists all of these articles. I want to be able to build out a webform where a user can select certain articles and then have it emailed to an address. I basically want to turn the Views list of articles into a radio button box where it can be selected for inclusion into the webform.

Are there any modules that can do this? Or how would one go about doing this if there is no module that supports this.

Comment: There is a sandbox project out there: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mrconnerton/1373760

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a big fan of webform, but in this use case, I would probably use [Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) and [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) instead.

Install both modules, and create your entity form.

Add a node reference field. On the field settings, narrow the results by content type "article".

Note, this would show all articles. If you were hoping to narrow down your results using views filters, you might want to investigate the [sandbox project](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mrconnerton/1373760) that Volker suggested.

Update: The References module allows you to use a view as a list of referenced nodes. This is very useful for drilling your results down to the exact nodes you want to show.